# Line breaks in SMS messages not working with messageContact API method

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

MobileConnect provides the support to include forced line breaks in a message. When creating a message in the MobileConnect interface, you can insert two return characters to create separate paragraphs, as defined by the screenshot below.

[image: MobileConnect line breaks]

When using the [MessageContact](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/push/postMessageContactSendPush.html) REST API method, you used to be able to achieve the same thing by including `\n\n` characters in the `messageText` value. Here's an example indicating that this **used** to work:

[image: with line breaks]

We haven't changed our API request at all, but note that line breaks are now suppressed. Here's my request:

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/Mzo3OXXX/send
Content-Type application/json
Authorization Bearer {{accessToken}}
{
   "Subscribers": [
{
   "MobileNumber": "61402649999",
   "SubscriberKey": "111112"
}
],
   "Override": true,
   "Subscribe": true,
   "Resubscribe": false,
   "Keyword":"CONSENTMO",
   "messageText": "This is one paragraph.\n\nAnd this is another paragraph."
}
```

And here's the SMS that I receive:

[image: line breaks not working]

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just guessing, but perhaps you can use the [Char()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/string/Char.html) AMPScript function and add some linefeeds:

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/Mzo3OXXX/send
Content-Type application/json
Authorization Bearer {{accessToken}}
{
   "Subscribers": [
{
   "MobileNumber": "61402649999",
   "SubscriberKey": "111112"
}
],
   "Override": true,
   "Subscribe": true,
   "Resubscribe": false,
   "Keyword":"CONSENTMO",
   "messageText": "This is one paragraph.%%=char(10)=%%%%=char(10)=%%And this is another paragraph."
}
```

Comment: Oh Adam, you really do have an answer for everything. You're right. AMPscript does the trick. I've used `"messageText": "This is one paragraph.%%=char(10,2)=%%And this is another paragraph."` and this inserts two line feeds into my SMS. Thanks!

Comment: AMPscript geniuses save my day again and again. Time to go back to school with ASCII table basics.